# VSTO itemadd Event not firing consistently

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am quite new to VSTO and C# programming and am self-learning.  I created an Outlook addin that does several things.  One of the features is that it takes all sent items and adds them to our DB.  When the user sends an email from Outlook it works as expected and prompts/adds it perfectly.  But when they sent an email from their phone it only prompt them for the last email sent.  I expected that once they open Outlook and it downloads the latest Sent items, it would prompt them for each item to save to the DB.  But it is only prompting the last downloaded item, not each one as they download. I think some sort of queue would be reqiured but I can't find any examples.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application application = this.Application;
    _items = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
    _items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(SentFolderItemAdded);
}

private void SentFolderItemAdded(object item)
{
// Code to prompt the user and add it to the DB
}
```

Comment: Do you mean for the messages send before your code was started as Outlook syncs the Sent Items folder on startup?

Comment: I mean messages sent from a iPhone while Outlook is closed. When outlook open again these message get sync’ed to the sent folder. As they sync I would like my addon to process them. Currently, if 5 messages sync, it only fires for the last one downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare the source object at the global scope (class level) to prevent it from being swiped from the heap by the GC.

```
Outlook.Items _items = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application application = this.Application;
    _items = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
    _items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(SentFolderItemAdded);
}

private void SentFolderItemAdded(object item)
{
// Code to prompt the user and add it to the DB
}
```

Be aware, the `ItemAdd` event is not fired when multiple items are added to the folder (more than sixteen). This is a known issue when dealing with the Outlook object model.

If items are synchronized from the Exchange server before you subscribe to the `ItemAdd` event you may filter items by using the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class. In that case you can deal with items that correspond to the search criteria. Read more about these methods in the following articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find a similar solution described for handling incoming emails (for the same situation), see [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/).

Comment: Does this line. Outlook.Items _items = null; Declare it at the class level. Is that what you mean?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change and it did not change the behaviour.

Comment: I have a message box where the user must choose whether to save the email.  I think this message box may be causing the issue.

Comment: Who is moving items to the `Sent Items` folder? Could you please describe the full scenario in what cases the event is not fired?

Comment: The way it works is when a new email is sent, immediately after sending, the user is presented with a message box asking if they want to save it to the DB.  if they click OK, it runs a process that saves it.    The problem is when more than one email is sent using their phone.

Comment: So if I go home to night and send 4 email from my phone.  Tomorrow when I open up outlook, I would like my Addin to process  each of those email as they are sync’ed to Outlook.  Right now it only processes the last one to sync, not all 4.

Comment: Such items are not sent and added to the `Sent Items` folder in your Outlook where the add-in resides. Instead, the items were sent out in your mobile application or the web browser. So, they will appear in the Sent Items folder after synchronizing with Exchange. In that case the `ItemAdd` event is not fired, it is for cases where items are put to the folder by Outlook or manually, not synchronized. I'd suggest marking synchronized items and look for new items at startup in addition to handling the `ItemAdd` event.

Comment: Thanks.  That is where I am headed now.  I appreciate your time. Thank you. 

Comment: I've added some links for reading about the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely old messages are synchronized to the cached folder before your code has a chance to set up an event sink on the folder on startup.

You can persist (registry etc.) the creation date of the last item you synchronized, and besides watching for the new items using the `ItemAdd` event, process all items newer than the saved date on startup using `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find`/`FindNext` with the search criteria based on the saved date.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  I will put a flag on Items sent from Outlook, so it will only find/fire on Items synced that were sent from external sources.    I am new to VSTO/C#, so most of my code is modified from examples.  Can you point me to an example of using  Items.Restrict or Items.Find/FindNext.  No worries if you can't.  Thanks for the awesome idea.  This will actually help a lot on another project I have in the pipe.

Comment: See examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict